# Making the table responsive in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, html-table

Currently my table is being cut off when my product page is loaded from mobile (see attached image).

What do i add to my css or html to make this aligned? 
Below is my html code.

You can view the product page for reference
https://www.sebuys.com/shop/windows-10-customised-i7-i5-7th-gen-rgb-gaming-tower-16gb-8gb-ddr4-pc-computer/

```php
Windows 10 Customised i7/i5 7th Gen RGB Gaming Tower 16GB / 8GB DDR4 PC Computer
<table class="shop_attributes">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Condition:</td>
<td>Brand New</td>
<td>Operating System Edition:</td>
<td>64bit Professional</td>
<td>Form Factor:</td>
<td>Gaming PC Tower</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Storage Type:</td>
<td>SSD &amp; SATA</td>
<td>MPN:</td>
<td>Does Not Apply</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Brand:</td>
<td>Custom, Whitebox</td>
<td>Windows 10</td>
<td>Windows 10</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
&nbsp;
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJUk6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are never responsive. All you can do is wrap the table in a div and apply overflow:auto to that div.

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```